# when I click item in my recyclerView, another item will click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

for my item layout in recycler view, I made a motion layout that will go to the end transition when clicked. but in my recycler view, for example when click 3nd item, the first item will change.
I know there is a lot of question like my title but none of those didn't solve my issue.
plus, any if else don't work in my item position of onBindViewHolder
I am using live data for my list and view binding and dont know its because of them or not but I tried it without them and issue didnt solved.
and I have a date chooser that will filter my list with queries of room database.
tell me if you need something else. I am at this issue for 2 weeks

ListAdapter.kt

```
class ListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var wordList = emptyList<Word>()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = WordRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = wordList[position]
        holder.bind(currentItem)

        if (position == 0) {
            holder.roundingCorners()
        }
        else{
            holder.notRoundingCorners()
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return wordList.size
    }


    class MyViewHolder(private val itemBinding: WordRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root){


        fun bind(currentItem: Word) {




                itemBinding.firstWordInWordRow.text = currentItem.EN_word


                itemBinding.secWordInWordRow.text = currentItem.FA_word


        }

        fun roundingCorners() {
            itemBinding.cardView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card1)
            itemBinding.cardView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card2)
        }
        fun notRoundingCorners() {
            itemBinding.cardView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card3)
            itemBinding.cardView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card3)
        }
    }


    fun setData(newWordList: List<Word>) {
        val diffUtil= MyDiffUtil(wordList,newWordList)
        val diffResults = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)
        wordList = newWordList
        diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "clickListener"

Example:

in view (layout ... xml)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="sleep"
            type="com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight" />

        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker.SleepNightListener" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(sleep)}">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quality_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:sleepImage="@{sleep}"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sleep_5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quality_string"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/quality_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/quality_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quality_image"
            app:sleepQualityString="@{sleep}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Into Adapter

```
/*
 * Copyright 2018, The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.R
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight
import com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.databinding.ListItemSleepNightBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0
private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1

class SleepNightAdapter(val clickListener: SleepNightListener) : ListAdapter<DataItem,
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(SleepNightDiffCallback()) {

    private val adapterScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    fun addHeaderAndSubmitList(list: List<SleepNight>?) {
        adapterScope.launch {
            val items = when (list) {
                null -> listOf(DataItem.Header)
                else -> listOf(DataItem.Header) + list.map { DataItem.SleepNightItem(it) }
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                submitList(items)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                val nightItem = getItem(position) as DataItem.SleepNightItem
                holder.bind(clickListener, nightItem.sleepNight)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER -> TextViewHolder.from(parent)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> ViewHolder.from(parent)
            else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType ${viewType}")
        }
    }

    class TextViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): TextViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false)
                return TextViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (getItem(position)) {
            is DataItem.Header -> ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER
            is DataItem.SleepNightItem -> ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ListItemSleepNightBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(clickListener: SleepNightListener, item: SleepNight) {
            binding.sleep = item
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ListItemSleepNightBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Callback for calculating the diff between two non-null items in a list.
 *
 * Used by ListAdapter to calculate the minumum number of changes between and old list and a new
 * list that's been passed to `submitList`.
 */
class SleepNightDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataItem>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DataItem, newItem: DataItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataItem, newItem: DataItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class SleepNightListener(val clickListener: (sleepId: Long) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(night: SleepNight) = clickListener(night.nightId)
}

sealed class DataItem {
    data class SleepNightItem(val sleepNight: SleepNight): DataItem() {
        override val id = sleepNight.nightId
    }

    object Header: DataItem() {
        override val id = Long.MIN_VALUE
    }

    abstract val id: Long
}
```

In the fragment

```
        val adapter = SleepNightAdapter(SleepNightListener { nightId ->
            sleepTrackerViewModel.onSleepNightClicked(nightId)
        })
```

Finally in viewModel

```
    fun onSleepNightClicked(id: Long) {
       //something
    }
```

Comment: i don't need click listener, i have a click listener defined in xml file. no need to add programmatically